# Cannot switch source with Apple TV 4 and Samsung TV

Tags: appletv

I just got the Apple TV 4th Gen and once I've it set up, I cannot change the input to my XBOX. Not through apple remote, the tv remote, or the button on the back of the TV. Please help. My Tv is Samsung UN70KU6300

Answer (score 1):

Apple TV 4th Gen does not play well with others. Turn off CEC (HDMI Control) on the TV. This means that you will have to manually change inputs when switching sources.

Answer (score 0):

Unplug and plug back in the TV fixed it...